# Тень от картинки PNG с прозрачным фоном

Tags: html, css

Имеется картинка с прозрачным фоном. Необходимо добавить тень. box-shadow добавляет по периметру, а нужно добавить к содержимому. Как это сделать. (Фотошоп самый простой способ, но не совсем подходит в данном контексте)

Comment: что такое содержимое ? о чём речь ?

Comment: Нужно "text-shadow" только для рисунка)

Comment: я не совсем понял , text-shadow это тень для текста - а img это ни текст , приведите пример

Comment: Это образное сравнение, имеется ввиду разница теней, как в text-shadow и box-shadow

Answer (score 4):

Используя

```css
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
filter:         drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
```

Comment: Очень сильно тормозит, к сожалению

Comment: это  фильтр не работает в IE и работает без префикса в Mozilla , не давно здесь мне сказали что хотят убрать поддержку этого тега во всех браузерах , в общем пришло время вообще убрать filter из "оборота"

Comment: Есть еще варианты?